# Multiple Weblogic versions on same Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, weblogic

Is it even possible to have multiple Weblogic server installations (with different versions) under the same eclipse IDE?

Although it seems doable (in fact, I managed to configure both instances ok), after installing a second weblogic server (12.2.1.3 first one, 10.3.0 second one) I keep getting strange behaviour.

The 12.2 weblogic starts and stops fine (this was the first version to be installed), but when I add the 10.3 and try to start it, looks like it's trying to start both servers at the same time. Also, it will timeout when trying to validate the server/domain, even though the server is up and running!

This may look like a very basic querstion but the closest one regarding this I was able to find here only talked about having different domains.

Screenshots:

Servers/different runtimes
[image: Servers]

10.3 Server startup
[image: 10.3 Server startup]

10.3 Server admin console
[image: 10.3 Server admin console]

Comment: I am wondering why you need 2 different versions of Weblogic at the same time. If you still need Why don't you try 2 different workspaces of Eclipse?

Comment: I need them for two different web apps that run on different server runtimes. I will give a try to the separate workspace approach, even though it's not perfect..

Comment: I've done this many times in the past, so it definitely works. You're not using the same domain folder, are you?

Comment: No, although they have the same name (base_domain), they are separate folders each inside its own server installation. Have you ever tried this on eclipse photon, or with the latest versions of OEPE?

Comment: If you start weblogic from outside Eclipse, does it start up correctly and does Eclipse see this?

Comment: It does, but due to a wrong weblogic version number I realised the newest versions of Eclipse do not support weblogic versions older than 10.3.6, and the one I needed to configure is 10.3.0.. so I'm giving up on this and I will have to set up a separate IDE for this legacy server.